# Manual Weblogic Basic Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, soap, weblogic

I have a Web Service (JAX-WS), a WSDL, a desktop application Client, and a Weblogic 12c server. I am trying to implement basic authentication between the `Client->Web Service->Weblogic->Active Directory`. I have been able to set everything up by putting the Username/Password in the header of the SOAP message when sending it from the Client to the Web Service.

Weblogic automatically pulls that header info and authenticates a user against Active Directory. Great. But the issues at hand are thse:

1. Should I ***not*** send credentials in the header *at all*, it doesn't authenticate but allows full access to anonymous users.

   - I need to send a proper error message and prevent anonymous usage.
2. Should I send ***invalid*** credentials it throws a `socket read` exception on the client.

   - I need to send back a proper error message; rather than having it bomb out on the client.
3. Should I send ***valid*** credentials but ***invalid*** authorization; I have setup `@RolesAllowed({"SomeRole"})` on each of my `Stateless EJB` methods. It throws a security vilotion exception on the Web Service side of the house.

   - I need to somehow catch this exception and send back a proper message to the client

Is there a way to do all of this without customizing the Weblogic Domain? It feels like I need to manually take control of the Basic Authentication of Weblogic but then I feel like I am stepping the `JAAS Login Module` of weblogic -- which customizes the domain and I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Use Handlers to intercept the incoming and outgoing requests.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: Inherit a class from SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> and override handleFault, getHeaders, and handleMessage to work with SOAP faults, SOAP messages' headers and SOAP messages' body.